# Can my ISP see documents I print trough my wireless network printer that is connected to ISP-provided router?

Tags: network, wireless, isp, printers

As stated in title - I am wondering if connecting my printer to ISP-provided router could expose all of my printed data to his eyes?

Cheers!

Comment: If your printer is not using secure channel for file transfer then your ISP can if your ISP monitors router activity.

Answer (score 1):

Any device on your network may be able to monitor unencrypted traffic traveling over your local network, whether passively or actively. A router is no exception to this.

I do not imagine that this is something ISPs normally do, as it is likely to raise quite a few eyebrows. However, if your ISP is compromised or malicious, it is possible that they could install new firmware on the router that does some of these things.

So, while possible, it's unlikely. But if this is a risk you cannot afford to take, it's yet another reason to consider providing your own hardware that only you control.